# Existence of non trivial solution of the equation a^2 + b^2=0 in Z_p

Tags: ring-theory

We are asked to make a conjecture about the existence of non-trivial solutions of the equation $a^2 + b^2=0$ in $Z_p$ ($p$ is prime) and the form of $p$. I am making it using $3$ cases: $p=2$; $p$ is of the form= $4k+1$ and when $p$ is of the form $4k+3$. Am I correct? I am not sure because I am not able to prove. But I think for making a conjecture we do not require to give proof.

Comment: Fine so far. Then notice that $a^2\equiv -b^2\pmod{p}$ implies that $-1$ is a square.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Sir please explain what are you trying to convey?

Comment: @akansha you have to find $p$ such that $-b^2$ is a square modulo $p$. Since $b^2$ is already a square, this implies $-1$ is a square modulo $p$. Do you know when is $-1$ a square?